# jquery autocomplete not showing under textbox

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery auto complete for my partial view page which act like pop up. the problem is complication is not showing under text box instead it's under my pop up page how do i fix that? Here is my code

```
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("SaveUserTask", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmTask" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    <label for="search">Search</label>
    <input id="autocomplete" title="type &quot;a&quot;"  name="autocomplete" style="height: 20px; width: 300px;"/>

}
<link href="~/Styles/jquery-ui-themes-1.10.0/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="jquery/jquery.js"type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>

$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
source: '@Url.Action("GetuserNames")'

});


public JsonResult GetuserNames(string term)
        {
            var db = new eEntities();
            var userNames = db.User.Where(s => s.UserName.StartsWith(term)).Select(s => s.UserName).ToList();

            return Json(userNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Any console errors you are getting?

Comment: no no error i see the list but it's not under the textbox  instead it's under the pop up page.

Comment: Just check whether proper classes have been applied to it from `autocomplete.css`